# Removing objects from Tiled Map after collision

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

Hello guys!

I'm creating a 2D-game similar to Mario Bros, by using Libgdx. I have watched Mario Bros tutorials on YouTube. I put diamonds inside Tiled map to make the player collects these diamonds. I have succeed with the collision. But, I have Two problems: 
-First, I can't make all diamonds disappear after the collision (just one diamond disappears).
- Second, if(f2.getUserData() instanceof Treasure) doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell(){
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(8);
    return  layer.getCell((int) (body.getPosition().x * MainGame.PPM / 64),
            (int) (body.getPosition().y * MainGame.PPM / 64));

}

if(f1.getUserData() == "HARRY" && f2.getUserData() == "COINS"){
        System.out.println("coins");
        //if(f2.getUserData() instanceof Treasure){
            System.out.println("Works");
         treasure.getCell().setTile(null);
        //}

    }
```

I expect diamonds will disappear when the player collides with.

But the result was, if I put (treasure.getCell().setTile(null);) inside if statement doesn't work. And, if I put it without the if statement just one diamond disappears, and not the one that the player collides with. The first diamond that I put inside the Tiled map disappears

Comment: Show more code. What is treasure and Treasure class? Where you  create it?

Answer (score 0):

**A couple concerning things...**

1. In Java `==` compares references when it comes to objects like `Strings` *(so only true if both are referencing the same object)*. So `f2.getUserData() == "COINS"` seems like it should be: `"COINS".equals((String) f2.getUserData())`, which will compare the actual character sequence of the `String` in question (also... `"COINS"` first to avoid any possible `NullPointerException`).
2. Based on your code, `if(f2.getUserData() instanceof Treasure)` is comparing a `Treasure` object to what seems like a `String` (unless `Treasure` extends `String` or something - I'm not familiar with the library you are using).

**Are you setting the value for `f2.getUserData()`?** If so, use a `Treasure` object instead of a `String` instance of "COINS". Maybe it has a constructor like this `Treasure coins = new Treasure("COINS")` or something.

3. This code: `treasure.getCell().setTile(null);` is referencing an object (that I assume is a `Treasure` object) that isn't defined in your sample code *(ie. Its probably defined somewhere above in your source compared to the sample code provided)*. Which is probably why only the one diamond is disappearing. I think you mean something more like this *(assuming `Treasure extends String` or something like that...)*:

   `if("HARRY".equals(f1.getUserData()) && "COINS".equals(f2.getUserData())){
       System.out.println("coins");
       if(f2.getUserData() instanceof Treasure){
           System.out.println("Works");
           ((Treasure)f2.getUserData()).getCell().setTile(null);
       }
    }`

Hope that helps and makes sense!